# Facebook webhooks for likes

Tags: json, facebook, webhooks

Can't find exact facebook webhook for likes, anyone knows what the json is look like in case of likes. And can I recognize the name of person, who liked?
Any help, guys?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: At most you can get them as part of the `feed` subscription, but there are a few limitations. Not sure you can get the user id though, you’d have to test it yourself. But even with the user id, you would only be able to get the corresponding name if the user logged in to your app and granted it permission to access their basic profile data first.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how to check, is app working or not? I could publish my app, but since I know every app should be approved by facebook, but when I pushed the button to publish, it published and I configured the access token of my test page for my app. Put the 'like' for publication, but it didn't send me the webhook. How can I know, is app working or not.